# Compare 2 arraylist of different size and put the values not equal in another array

Tags: java, arraylist

I've 2 arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> listdes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listmet = new ArrayList<String>();
```

listdes contains 22 elements:

```
[getCostruttore/{code}, searchZona/{codice : .+}/{descri : .+}, searchAgent/{codcon : .+}/{descra : .+}, getZona/{code}, searchArticolo/{codint : .+}/{coarfo : .+}/{descri : .+}, getCustomer/{code : .+}, searchPayment/{pagame}/{despag : .+}, getPayment/{code}, getGruppo/{sigcos}/{codgru}, getSottoGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{codsgr : .+}, getCustomers, searchGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{desgru : .+}, getAgent/{code : .+}, getArticolo/{codint : .+}/{coarfo : .+}, getFido/{client : .+}/{dataat : .+}/{datafi : .+}, searchStructureAgent/{codice}/{descri : .+}, getStructureAgent/{code}, getFidoClienteOasi/{client : .+}, searchSottoGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{codsgr : .+}/{dessgr : .+}, getArboAnagrafica/{codice : .+}, searchCostruttore/{sigcos : .+}/{dessig : .+}, searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi/{client : .+}]
```

while listmet contains 20 elements:

```
[getCostruttore, searchZona, searchAgent, getZona, searchArticolo, getCustomer, searchPayment, getPayment, getGruppo, getSottoGruppo, getCustomers, searchGruppo, getAgent, getArticolo, getFido, searchStructureAgent, getStructureAgent, getFidoClienteOasi, searchSottoGruppo, getArboAnagrafica]
```

I want to compare (if possible with an contains operator) and put tha values that are not the same in another arraylist

I try to use Hashset but it doesn't work.. here the code

```
for(int i =0;i<listdes.size();i++)
            {
                if(listdes.get(i).equals(listmet.get(i)))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    //put on another arraylist
                }
            }
```

the arrays are sorted.. the result i want is

arraylist: [{searchCostruttore,searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi }]

output List leftover:

```
[searchStructureAgent/{codice}/{descri : .+}, getStructureAgent/{code}, getCustomer/{code : .+}, getZona/{code}, getCostruttore/{code}, searchGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{desgru : .+}, searchPayment/{pagame}/{despag : .+}, searchZona/{codice : .+}/{descri : .+}, searchAgent/{codcon : .+}/{descra : .+}, getPayment/{code}, getAgent/{code : .+}, searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi/{client : .+}, searchCostruttore/{sigcos : .+}/{dessig : .+}, searchSottoGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{codsgr : .+}/{dessgr : .+}, getArboAnagrafica/{codice : .+}, getFidoClienteOasi/{client : .+}, getFido/{client : .+}/{dataat : .+}/{datafi : .+}, searchArticolo/{codint : .+}/{coarfo : .+}/{descri : .+}, getSottoGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{codsgr : .+}, getGruppo/{sigcos}/{codgru}, getArticolo/{codint : .+}/{coarfo : .+}]
```

it returns me an array of 21 elements

Comment: @Arnaud no, it isn't the same

Comment: You can just do `listdes.removeAll(listmet)` and vice versa. Create a temporary lists if you want to have the original lists unchanged

Comment: @Sabesh remove all doesn't work

Comment: @mego removeAll actually works for your use case. It will give you the expected result. I'm not sure on what have you missed

Comment: @Sabesh it returns me 21 elements

Comment: 21 elements is the correct answer for you example lists. Apparently, you actually do not want to use equality, so the problem lies in your task description.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> listdes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listmet = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> similar = new ArrayList<String>();
listdes.forEach(des -> {
    Optional<String> opt = listmet.stream().filter(met -> des.contains(met)).findFirst();
    if (opt.isPresent()) {
        similar.add(opt.get());
    }
});
List<String> leftover = listmet.stream().filter(met -> !similar.contains(met)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ok now I try to do it

Comment: it returns me an array of 21 elements.. the result exactly is 22

Comment: i update the question

Comment: @mego do you mean to check if the string contains in another? instead of equals

Comment: I want to check if the string contains in another

Comment: @mego updated, please try